# Writing in Meteor using ClojureScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, clojurescript, meteorite

Is there currently a solution for integrating ClojureScript with Meteor?

I want to build a Meteor application and between the flavors of JavaScript (JavaScript, CoffeeScript, TypeScript, LiveScript and ClojureScript) I find ClojureScript the nicest.  I have found atmosphere/meteorite packages for the other JavaScript substitues but no ClojureScript.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ClojureScript compiles to Javascript so you can use it with Meteor. This blog post explains the necessary steps to use ClojureScript with Meteor:

http://undefined.re/tag-article/6

This blog is the only resource that I found that is specific to your question, but there are more resources on how to use ClojureScript on Node.js. For example, this [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MTxNnYfWHOw) shows how to create a ClojureScript application running on Node.js and the ClojureScript [wiki](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Quick-Start#running-clojurescript-on-nodejs) explains how to run ClojureScript on Node.js.

Comment: That link is a 404 now.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/samvit/meteor-clojurescript looks like something to look into.

[wisp](https://atmospherejs.com/nsmeta/wisp) is not ClojureScript but it can be easily installed through `mrt add wisp`. Could also be a good starting point to make a ClojureScript package in Atmosphere.